# Connecting Rstudio and SFTP docker containers directly

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rstudio, sftp, rstudio-server

I'm trying to run RStudio Server in a docker container.  Users will connect to this docker container and use RStudio via the internet.

The built-in mechanism for uploading and downloading files in Rstudio is very slow so I'd also like to run an SFTP server in a separate container.

I'm trying to link the two containers using Docker Volumes but I'm having some trouble.  Here's is how I'm trying to run the two images.

I'm running the FTP sever using:

`docker run -p 2222:22 -v /home/rstudio --name ftpserver -d atmoz/sftp rstudio:foo:1001`

Then I'm trying to connect to the same directory in RStudio by doing:

`docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=foo --volumes-from ftpserver --name rstudio r-studio-bio:Dockerfile`

This causes RStudio to give an error

`RStudio Initialization Error.  Unable to connect to service.`

Likewise I'm unable to upload to the FTP server because it's saying I lack the proper permissions.

The FTP server image is here : https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp/

The RStudio-Server Dockerfile is:

```
# See the following for more info:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/pgensler/sandboxr/
# https://www.rocker-project.org/images/
# https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio

FROM rocker/tidyverse
LABEL maintainer="Alex"
#

RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.R
RUN mkdir $HOME/Rlibs
ENV R_LIBS $HOME/Rlibs
# COPY R/Makevars /root/.R/Makevars

RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    curl \
    clang  \
    ccache \
    default-jdk \
    default-jre \
    wget \
    systemd \
    # openssh-server \
    && R CMD javareconf \
    # && systemctl ssh start \
    # && systemctl enable ssh \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

# # Install additional R packages
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install()"
RUN Rscript -e "BiocManager::install('multtest')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('Seurat')"
```